# PyQt5 won't install for Python 3

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5

I'm trying to install PyQt5 desperately. So far I've tried it on OSx Mavericks, an Ubuntu VM and a W7 VM. Nothing seems to work. This is what I've tried.

### OSx

I've tried Homebrew

```
brew update
brew install PyQt5
```

Output from `brew install` command:

```
==> Installing dependencies for pyqt5: qt5, sip    
==> Installing pyqt5 dependency: qt5    
==> Downloading http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.1/si    
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/qt5-5.1.1.tar.gz    
==> ./configure -prefix /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.1.1 -system-zlib -confirm-licens    
==> make    
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -single_module -dynamiclib -o libqsqlite.dylib .obj/release-shared/smain.o .obj/release-shared/qsql_sqlite.o .obj/release-shared/sqlite3.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qsql_sqlite_p.o  -F/private/tmp/qt5-jmbp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/qtbase/lib -framework QtSql -framework QtCore      
mv -f libqsqlite.dylib ../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/     
make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2    
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2    
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2    

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting    

These open issues may also help:    
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23699    
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23480    
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/22283    
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23806
```

I've tried all the issues and the troubleshooting. Nothing seems to help.

I also tried to install it manually:
    sudo python3 configure.py --qmake=/Users/Thomas/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/bin/qmake --sip=/Users/Thomas/Downloads/sip-4.15.3/sipgen/sip

Works fine. Then, when I try `sudo make` it keeps giving me:

```
    In file included from ../../../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:70:    
../../../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/include/QtCore/qsystemdetection.h:243:6: warning:     
      "This version of OS X is unsupported" [-W#warnings]    
      #    warning "This version of OS X is unsupported"    
     ^    
     1 warning generated.
```

I would think this warning doesn't matter because qglobal.h defines the max-version as 10.8, while I run the 10.9.

`sudo make install` doesn't give me any errors but when I try to run Python as super user (`sudo python3`), and try `dir(PyQt5)` Python crashes. Note that the package is found.

Read somewhere that I need the Python Development Header. So I compiled Python3.3.2 from source on OSx. This gives me nothing better..

### Windows

Haven't tried this much. Seems to install with the binary GUI installer. Problem here is that `dir(PyQt5)` lists some default Python stuff (with the underscores), but nothing actual from Qt*..
Don't know much about Windows and I don't want to (VM is really slow).

### Ubuntu

No errors or warnings during install (exact same commands as used during OSx install process), but Python also breaks when I try `dir(PyQt5)`. No error or whatsoever.

I've tried searching every error I got, some results got me going again. Though, this is where I get stuck and probably stop. If anyone know anything, please help.

Comment: try `python configure.py` `make` `make install` that worked for me like a charm on 3.3.2 linux no errors at all. if it doesn't work it must have to do with dependancies.

Comment: Check your ubuntu installation again. `dir(PyQt5)` is misleading, because it is just a package namespace and won't show anything interesting. Try doing `from PyQt5 import QtCore; dir(QtCore)`.

Comment: Here's a nice write-up for installing on OS X: http://danmarner.com/2014/04/23/Installing-PyQt5-with-Python-3-On-OS-X.html

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to install `PyQt5` in Mac OS X (including Yosemite) by standard/easy ways at this moment. I've tried everything but only one thing worked - compiling and install it. In this action here is nothing hard to do, I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vityafx/e01ab56d28a2c9467cc6) with steps to install `pyqt5` on Yosemite.